# How can I execute code on "Prune stale remote-tracking branches" in jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

When a branch is removed I'd like to execute additional clean up code for things like artifacts created by the job (e.g. AMIs, docker images, terraform services). I'm using the declarative pipelines, is there a hook or plugin that allows me to achieve this?

Answer (score 6):

There's an option for this under ***Additional Behaviours*** in the Pipeline section. Note the pipeline script from SCM definition is selected here.

[image: Pipeline script from SCM]

This can also be done in the pipeline script with the ***checkout*** step.
https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/

`$class: PruneStaleBranch`

Example generated with the Jenkins Snippet Generator:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations: false, extensions: [[$class: 
'PruneStaleBranch']], submoduleCfg: [], userRemoteConfigs: 
[[credentialsId: 'credential-id-here', url: 'git@github.com:my-
repo.git']]])
```

Comment: I don't have this section in my multi-branch pipeline configuration, I do have a spot to specify a script, but that's the global jenkinsfile, not just something that executes on "prune". I have the prune stale branches option too, but it doesn't include the option to take additional actions.

Comment: added how to do it from your pipeline script as well.

Comment: how does this do additional cleanup of things like artifacts when the branch is deleted? how would this execute `docker rmi ...` ? or something like that?

Comment: Thanks but is it only me or someone else thinks that jenkins document should have some indention to let reader know what goes inside what. I did ctrl+f 'Prune' to find 'PruneStaleBranch' but it wasn't easy to understand it is parameter of 'extensions' without this answer.

Comment: I can't see how this answers the question. This seems to be stating how to actually enable the prune option (either in job config or pipeline definition). But the question is when the prune runs, how can we run additional cleanup behaviour for it. This is what I'm also trying to do: delete external artifacts created from a branch when it gets pruned.

Answer (score 1):

I am yet to try it but the **MultiBranch Action Triggers Plugin** plugin looks like it would allow you to do this:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/multibranch-action-triggers

It says:

> This plugin enables building/triggering other jobs when a Pipeline job
>   is created or deleted by Multi Branch Pipeline Job.

You could create a cleanup job that runs whatever cleanup code you need, triggered by this plugin. You set the plugin up on your multi branch pipeline job and specify the additional job to run.

If I understand the docs correctly it looks like `SOURCE_PROJECT_NAME` is a then a parameter passed to your cleanup job that you can use to cleanup relating to that branch name.